# Facebook like table cell for comments and Reply(iOS)

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uitableview

I have an app which includes a feature where in the user can add comments and reply to a comment on any images/videos (like facebook). The user can delete/edit a  comment/reply posted. I want to know if there are any classes available to show this kind of UI.

I have designed the above using tableview and added custom cell with dynamic cell size(For large size comments). The problem is when there is no reply on a comment i hide the uiview (which contains reply data) and show it if there is any reply on the comment. Therefore the dynamic cell then shows a lot of whitespace if there are no reply on a comment. I wish to avoid it. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.